# How to populate categories in one column and paste the exact value in other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

It has been a long time that I dealt with pandas library. I searched for it but could not come up with an efficient way, which might be a function existed in the library.

Let's say I have the dataframe below:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'V1':['A','A','B'],
                   'V2':['B','C','C'],
                   'Value':[4, 1, 5]})
df1
```

[image]

And I would like to extend this dataset and populate all the combinations of categories and put its corresponding value as exactly the same.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'V1':['A','B','A', 'C', 'B', 'C'],
                   'V2':['B','A','C','A','C','B'],
                   'Value':[4, 4 , 1, 1, 5, 5]})
df2
```

[image]

In other words, in df1, A and B has Value of 4 and I also want to have a row of that B and A has Value of 4 in the second dataframe. It is very similar to melting. I also do not want to use a for loop. I am looking for a more efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df1.rename(columns={'V2':'V1', 'V1':'V2'})]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2  Value
0  A  B      4
1  B  A      4
2  A  C      1
3  C  A      1
4  B  C      5
5  C  B      5
```

Answer (score 2):

Or `np.vstack`:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((df1.to_numpy(), df1.iloc[:, np.r_[1:-1:-1, -1]].to_numpy())), columns=df1.columns)
  V1 V2 Value
0  A  B     4
1  A  C     1
2  B  C     5
3  B  A     4
4  C  A     1
5  C  B     5
>>>
```

For correct order:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((df1.to_numpy(), df1.iloc[:, np.r_[1:-1:-1, -1]].to_numpy())), columns=df1.columns, index=[*df1.index, *df1.index]).sort_index()
  V1 V2 Value
0  A  B     4
0  B  A     4
1  A  C     1
1  C  A     1
2  B  C     5
2  C  B     5
>>>
```

And index reset:

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(np.vstack((df1.to_numpy(), df1.iloc[:, np.r_[1:-1:-1, -1]].to_numpy())), columns=df1.columns, index=[*df1.index, *df1.index]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
  V1 V2 Value
0  A  B     4
1  B  A     4
2  A  C     1
3  C  A     1
4  B  C     5
5  C  B     5
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods `assign` and `append`:

```
df1.append(df1.assign(V1=df1.V2, V2=df1.V1), ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
  V1 V2  Value
0  A  B      4
1  A  C      1
2  B  C      5
3  B  A      4
4  C  A      1
5  C  B      5
```